# Python Chatbot doesn't quit when commanded to

Tags: python, while-loop, chatbot, chatterbot

When I type "quit" into the chatbot, it should stop working, but it doesn't. Have any idea why so?

```py
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
    from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
    from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
    import chatterbot_corpus

    chatbot = ChatBot("hi")

    def talk_to(chatbot):
  
      keep_going = "yes"
      while keep_going == "yes":
    
        user_input = input("Type Here: ")
        response = chatbot.get_response(user_input)
        print(response)
        trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot) 
  
      trainer.train(response)
      if user_input == "quit":
          keep_going = "no" 

    talk_to(chatbot)
```

Comment: Your if statement is outside your while loop. The indentation matters in python. So you never hit the if statement in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import chatterbot_corpus

chatbot = ChatBot("hi")
user_input = input("Type hi to start.")
def talk_to(chatbot):
  while user_input != "quit":
    user_input = input("Type Here: ")
    response = chatbot.get_response(user_input)
    print(response)
    trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot) 

  trainer.train(response)

talk_to(chatbot)
```

`Edit`: There's no need of using `keep_going`. You can directly set the condition on `user_input`.

Comment: I am now getting the error  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    talk_to(chatbot)
  File "main.py", line 18, in talk_to
    trainer.train(response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chatterbot/trainers.py", line 81, in train
    for text in conversation:
TypeError: 'Statement' object is not iterable


what should I do

Comment: @Abstrakt I have edited the code please check if it works now.